# how to get the contact infomation by sms message

Tags: android

I'm working on an extend SMS application. And now i can read all the SMS message from the mmssms.db. In the SMS database table, the field 'person' indicate the '_id' in contact table. When 'person' is >= 1, that means the message is sent from people in the contact list. So i can 'managedQuery' from contact table. But the question is, in my mobile phone, the test program sometimes can NOT query the contact infomation even 'person' >= 1.  So can somebody show me some correct ways to query contact infomation by 'person' filed in SMS table ?
Here is some sample code which can make my question more clear:

```
class ContactItem {  
    public String mName;  
}  

    ContactItem getContact(Activity activity, final SMSItem sms) {  
        if(sms.mPerson == 0) return null;  
        Cursor cur = activity.managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,   
                new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},   
                " _id=?",   
               new String[] {String.valueOf(sms.mPerson)}, null);  
       if(cur != null &&  
           cur.moveToFirst()) {  
           int idx = cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);  
           ContactItem item = new ContactItem();  
           item.mName = cur.getString(idx);  
           return item;  
       }  
       return null;  
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, as there is no one help me out, i tried to read some open source project code, and i got answer now. As i supposed at the very beginning, the best way to query the contact information from a SMS message, is to query by the NUMBER(also know as ADDRESS):

```
   ContactItem getContactByAddr(Context context, final SMSItem sms) {  
    Uri personUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(  
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, sms.mAddress);  
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(personUri,  
            new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME },  
            null, null, null );  
    if( cur.moveToFirst() ) {  
        int nameIdx = cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);  
        ContactItem item = new ContactItem();  
        item.mName = cur.getString(nameIdx);  
       cur.close();  
       return item;  
   }  
   return null;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I'm so grateful! You know... I've tried to learn from about 30 samples I've found online in the last week and none of them actually worked.Your one works perfectly. I need to find a way to optimize it a little, since the screen is blank for a few seconds while it's getting all the messages and contacts - but atleast it gets all contacts now :)